# Nuget restore not working under TeamCity 10.0.3 (build 42434)

Tags: nuget, teamcity

I has `nuget` in PATH for version 3.5.0.

`nuget restore solution.sln` in `C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\xxxx` works as expected.

Same code TeamCity CommandLine step not works, only this in log:

```
Restoring packages for C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\92c1a2b89cb52a9a\src\Models\project.json...
[17:38:14][Step 1/6] Committing restore...
[17:38:14][Step 1/6] Writing lock file to disk. Path: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\92c1a2b89cb52a9a\src\Models\project.lock.json
[17:38:14][Step 1/6] C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\92c1a2b89cb52a9a\src\Models\Models.csproj
[17:38:14][Step 1/6] Restore completed in 762ms.
...
```

wihtout any `GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/moq/index.json`

`C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages` still empty.

I do not know after what changes in TeamCity this stopped working (there was packages from previouse build in `...systemprofile` before I manulally clean it).

[NuGet 3.3 restore not creating packages when running as LocalSystem](https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207284185-NuGet-3-3-restore-not-creating-packages-when-running-as-LocalSystem) issue describes same symptoms, but still opened.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the Nuget.exe path is specified under Administration->Integrations->Tools

[ScreenShot of added nuget tool path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XCSS.png)

Comment: Yes it is, but I'm use `nuget` command explicitly, nuget runs but not successfully. Like it cannot work under systemprofile.

Answer (score 0):

nuget cannot restore Core projects

First need to remove `project.lock.json`, then `dotnet restore`